# Grails - Unable to find a way to render the overlay using fancybox

Tags: jquery, grails

```
class ImageController {

    def more() {
        def id = params.int('id')
        def image = Image.read(id)
        def max = params.max ?: 8
        def tags = image.tags ?: image.title

        tags = tags.replaceAll("Tagged","")?.split(",")?.join(" ")
        tags = tags.replaceAll("-", " ")
        tags = tags.replaceAll(":", " ")
        tags = tags.replaceAll(".com", " ")
        tags += " active:true"
        def searchOptions = [max:max, defaultOperator: "or", defaultProperty:'description']
        def similarImages = Image.search(tags, searchOptions)
        if (!image) {
            reponse.sendError(404)
            return
        }

        def filteredList = similarImages?.results?.unique { it.id }
        def others = []
        filteredList?.each { r ->
            if (r.id == image.id) return
            others << r
        }

        params.max = Math.min(params.int('max') ?: 20, 100)
        params.offset = params.int('offset', 0)
        params.sort = 'id'

        def list = []
        def count = 0 //Image.count()
        def options = [order:'desc', sort:'rank', max:params.max, offset:params.offset]
        list = Image.findAllByActive(true, options)

        if(!request.xhr){ // not ajax
            render(view:'notAjax', model:[list:list], id:params.id)
        }

        else{
            [image:image, similarImages: others]
        }

    }

    //same as front page except when click + right on link,
    //it will show the broken layout
    def notAjax(){
        params.max = Math.min(params.int('max') ?: 20, 100)
        params.offset = params.int('offset', 0)
        params.sort = 'id'

        String filter = params.filter

        if (filter == null || "all".equalsIgnoreCase(filter)) {
            filter = null
        }

        def list = []
        def count = 0 //Image.count()
        def options = [order:'desc', sort:'rank', max:params.max, offset:params.offset]

        if (filter) {
            list = Image.findAllByImageTypeAndActive(filter, true, options)
            count = Image.countByImageTypeAndActive(filter, true)
        } else {
            list = Image.findAllByActive(true, options)
            count = Image.countByActive(true)
        }


        //grails output js to trigger js for fancybox
        //grails output the js code to trigger the fancybox


        [list:list, params:params, count:count]
    }

}

//New Template
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <title></title>

    <r:require module="freewall" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div data-freewall class="cly-pos-re">
      <g:each in="${list}" var="image">
        <%
          def _model = [
            link: '/image/more/' + image.id,
            imgSrc: image.referralImage,
            title: image.coverTitle(),
            modelClass: 'image',
            id: image.id,
            showFancy: true,
          ]
        %>
        <div>
          <a href="${link}" class="${showFancy ? 'fancybox' : ''}">
            <span>
              <g:if test="${ratio}">
                <span style="background-image: url('${imgSrc}');"
                  ></span>
              </g:if>
              <g:else>
                <img src="${imgSrc}" alt="Display image of ${title}">
              </g:else>
            </span>
            <span>
              ${title}
              <small>${subtitle}</small>
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>

      </g:each>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



//JQuery
jQuery(function($) {
  $.fn.fanccy = function() {
    this.fancybox({
      type: 'ajax',
      autoHeight: true,
      width: 930,
      autoSize: false,
      autoCenter: true,
      fitToView: false,
      topRatio: 0,
      arrows: false,
      closeBtn: false,
      autoPlay: false,
      openSpeed: 1,
      closeSpeed: 'fast',
      closeClick: false,
      helpers: {
        overlay: {
          openSpeed: 'fast',
          closeSpeed: 'fast',
          speedOut: 200,
          css: {
            'cursor': 'pointer'
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };

  $('.fancybox').fanccy();
});
```

The index page displays full listing using freewall grids as similar as notAjax. Then click on a image link and will see the fancybox pop with image details (with hidden url address: image/123).

The problem is when click + right select the new tab on image link on the listing, a new tab opens and shows the broken layout because of no ajax being used for fancybox - instead the broken layout shows only details and the url address will show /image/123.

So try to make duplicate for notAjax template to display the listing and have the fancybox appear but no to avail :-?

Any idea or help would be appreciated.

**edit #2**

wonder if create fake element in ajax request in new template notAjax.gsp and overlay opens invisible to user, the fancybox could be opened on its own when notAjax is rendered?

Comment: Try `link: "${g.createLink(controller: 'image', action: 'more')}" + image.id,` in your scriptlet tag..,.

Comment: @user1690588 - i m sorry which part it needs to be in?

Comment: @user1690588 - oh ok and then i tried that, but no affect. the problem is that if ajax is not rendered, then fancybox should be still open on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I been it a few times now and if you wanted to try the fake page which does a get i.e. it ends up twice you could do something like this

```
<div id="stuff">
.. if somehow original data ended up here
</div>
<g:javascript>

var something="${params.something}";
var another="${another}";

   $.get('${createLink(controller:"${attrs.queryController}", action: "${attrs.queryAction}")}?domain=&templateType=Form&fromsomething='+something+'&another='+another+'&returnController='+returnController,function(data){
$('#${stuff}').hide().append(data);
});
</g:javascript>
```

This will get the data and put it inside the div called stuff..
[quite a few examples here](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/modaldynamix/tree/master/grails-app/views/modaldynamix)

Comment: thanks and i am not sure what is hidden and then appended to data? I only want to make fake element which would trigger overlay and fancybox auto shows.

Comment: the div <div id="stuff"> its content is hidden then the get function gets content from controller action with params passed to it. The return data called data is appended back to the element stuff. so in essence if that div had content its removed and then replaced with the return result of the get call